# How to find the immediate integer value written before a string?

Tags: c#, regex

How to find the immediate integer value written before a string in c#? For example

**50+ boxes were ordered, however only 2 are delivered.**

I need to know the number of boxes (integer value) written just before "delivered". The output should be 2. I have written a code in c# using Regex:

```
string line = "50+ boxes were ordered, however only 2 are delivered.";
string boxesDelivered = Regex.Match(line, @"\d+").Value;
//The output I get is 50 instead of 2.
```

Comment: Use `\b\d+\b(?=[^\d]*delivered)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> written just before delivered

I'm going to take that verbatim as your user requirement - find the last number in the string that appears before "delivered".

You can use `(\d+)[^\d]*(?:delivered)`, which says "match any sequence of numbers that does not occur before another sequence of numbers and does occur before `delivered`".

```
string line = "50+ boxes were ordered, however only 2 are delivered.";
string boxesDelivered = Regex.Match(line, @"(\d+)[^\d]*(?:delivered)").Groups[1].Value;
// boxesDelivered = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the last number that is followed by the word "delivered", you may use the following pattern:

```
\b\d+\b(?=[^\d]*\bdelivered\b)
```

**[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5cb%5cd%2b%5cb%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%5cd%5d*%5cbdelivered%5cb%29&i=50%2b+boxes+were+ordered%2c+however+only+2+are+delivered.)**.

Here's a full example:

```
string line = "50+ boxes were ordered, however only 2 are delivered.";

var match = Regex.Match(line, @"\b\d+\b(?=[^\d]*\bdelivered\b)");
if (match.Success)
{
    string boxesDelivered = match.Value;
    // TODO: convert the value to a numeric type or use it as is.

}
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/UKZY8927)**.

Comment: This worked for me thnx :)